# Sweepstakes algorithm

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, security, cryptography

I am doing a internet cafe sweepstakes slot game in vb.net. I want to show the objects based on the payout and the prize money for paylines in the slot game. I tried using MT algorithem but it basically random number based. the final output should not be radom.

### Inputs

1. Points Ex. 18 or 50 (2 entries) 9 or 25 (1 Entry)
2. prize (from database) Ex. 200 cents
3. Total Lines Ex. 9 or 25
4. 1 Line = Points/Lines (18/9) = 2 Points
5. Reels = 5
6. Rows = 3
7. Pay Table\Pay out = 10 Arrays 
   Ex. obj1(0) = 0, obj1(1) = 20,obj1(2) = 100,obj1(3) = 300,obj1(4) = 2000,
8. Line array 
   Example:
   L1 (2,1)(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5) = 2 Points = 15 cents
   L2 (1,1 )(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5) = 2 Points = 300 cents
   L3 (3,1)(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5) = 2 Points = 30 cents
   L4 (1,1)(2,2),(3,3),(2,4),(1,5) = 2 Points = 200 cents
   L5 (3,1)(2,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,5) = 2 Points = 0 cents
   L6 (2,1)(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(2,5) = 2 Points = 20 cents
   L7 (2,1)(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,5) = 2 Points = 6 cents
   L8 (1,1)(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(1,5) = 2 Points = 0 cents
   L9 (3,1)(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,5) = 2 Points = 10 cents

### Output

3 X 5 Matrix

Comment: I cannot understand this question but it looks an awful lot like homework.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft so then should it get a homework tag?

Comment: @Rook: No, we usually give people the benefit of the doubt first.

Answer (score 0):

With any random number generator you have to [seed its input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436376/what-is-the-most-secure-seed-for-random-number-generation).  For random number on windows platform your best off just using `CryptGenRandom()`.  Keep in mind that time() alone is a very bad seed because often times the attacker knows the time.

```
  <DllImport("coredll.dll")> _
  Public Shared Function CryptGenRandom( _
     ByVal hProv As IntPtr, ByVal dwLen As Integer, _
     ByVal pbBuffer() As Byte) As Boolean
  End Function
```