# Does a Good Password Salt Need to Include Both Numbers and Letters?

Tags: security, passwords, password-protection

I am salting newly created passwords before hashing them with an encryption algorithm.  I generate my salts using a random number function.

Are you compromising security if your salts are only comprised of numbers (with no letters) or does this make no difference at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4983915/10396 answers most common questions about salting passwords.

Comment: Also of interest: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16117/in-hashing-does-it-matter-how-random-a-salt-is/16119

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these 2 posts talk about the added security (if any) of having a salt with both numbers and letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A salt should be **unique** (ideally for every password in the world), and **unpredictable**. The best you can do with a deterministic computer is, to get a random number, and hope that the returned value is *nearly* unique. So the more possible combinations you have, the bigger is the chance that the salt is unique.

Some hash algorithms define a number and an alphabet of accepted characters. PHP's BCrypt for example, expects a salt containing 22 characters from this alphabet:

```
./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

You get the most possible combinations, using **all** characters of the alphabet, and not only the characters 0-9. Of course a longer salt with a small alphabet (0-9) can have as much combinations, as a shorter salt with a big alphabet (0-9,a-z,...).

To make it short, use all possible characters, and as many characters as your hash algorithm expects.

P.S: If you use a key-derivation function like BCrypt (and you really should), then you cannot salt the password befor hashing, instead you have to pass the salt to the hash function.

Comment: I never heard of an unpredictability requirement for password hashes. And concerning more=better, after about 64 bits the gain becomes pretty small, and at around 128 bits increasing salt size won't help at all.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - You are right, that there is no need to make salts very long, that's why BCrypt only expects 22 characters (5.4E39 combinations), anyway i changed the text slightly. A salt should be unpredictable, because otherwise an attacker could make [precalculations](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/17480/8343). An extreme example would be an increasing salt starting with 1 (userid), and an admin account as the first account.