# How to implement a fast RNG?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I am trying to port an existing random generator based on 128 bit XorShift from `C`. But I have trouble with generating the seed which is just generating the same number again and again.

```c
static uint64_t s[ 2 ];

static uint64_t __inline next(void) {
    uint64_t s1 = s[ 0 ];
    const uint64_t s0 = s[ 1 ];
    s[ 0 ] = s0;
    s1 ^= s1 << 23;
    return ( s[ 1 ] = ( s1 ^ s0 ^ ( s1 >> 17 ) ^ ( s0 >> 26 ) ) ) + s0;
}

uint64_t getusertime() {
    struct rusage rusage;
    getrusage( 0, &rusage );
    return rusage.ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + ( rusage.ru_utime.tv_usec / 1000 ) * 1000;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    const long long int n = strtoll( argv[1], NULL, 0 );
    uint64_t t = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) s[ i ] = -1ULL / 3;

    const int64_t start = getusertime();

    for( long long int i = n; i-- != 0; ) t ^= next();

    const int64_t elapsed = getusertime() - start;
    const double secs = elapsed / 1E6;
    printf( "%f s, %.02f queries/s, %.02f ns/query\n", secs, n / secs, 1E9 * secs / n );
    if ( t == 0 ) putchar( 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

```pascal
program Project1;

var
  S: Array [0..1] of UInt64;

function XorShift128: UInt64;
var
  s0, s1: UInt64;
begin
  s1 := s[0];
  s0 := s[1];
  s[0] := s0;
  s1 := s1 xor (s1 shl 23);
  s[1] := (s1 xor s0 xor (s1 shr 17) xor (s0 shr 26));
  Result := s[1] + s0;
end;

procedure GenerateSeed;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to High(S) do
  S[I] := MaxLongInt div 3;
end;

var
  I: UInt64;
begin 
  GenerateSeed;
  I := XorShift128;
end.
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. Where is the real code? What output do you expect? What output do you observe? If you have supposedly equivalent C code, why can you debug to find where differences arise?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I observe the same numbers, I expect random numbers..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The same number over and over again in variable `I`.

Comment: It is no surprise that your program always produces the same number. What do you expect if your seed does not change? Include some random/entropy in `GenerateSeed`.

Comment: Aren't you calling `GenerateSeed` repeatedly ? You should call it once. Also, as @gammatester says, it should be a random value.

Comment: @gammatester And how can I do that? Populate with what? `GetTickCount` ?

Comment: Use `randomize` an the start of your program and replace `S[I] := MaxLongInt div 3;` eg by `S[I] := random(MaxLongInt div 3)`;

Comment: @gamma That's only 64 bits of seed. We need 128 really.

Comment: @gammatester you need `Randomize` for `Random` and that is not really thread safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get the same value every time you run the program in the question is that you use the same seed every time. If I am understanding your comments correctly. The other difference between the C and the Pascal is the seed – see below.

However, your code is fine and is an accurate translation of the C code. The output of this C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint64_t s[ 2 ];

static uint64_t __inline next(void) {
    uint64_t s1 = s[ 0 ];
    const uint64_t s0 = s[ 1 ];
    s[ 0 ] = s0;
    s1 ^= s1 << 23;
    return ( s[ 1 ] = ( s1 ^ s0 ^ ( s1 >> 17 ) ^ ( s0 >> 26 ) ) ) + s0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    s[ 0 ] = s[ 1 ] = 715827882; // the value of MaxLongInt div 3
    printf("%llu\n", next());
    printf("%llu\n", next());
    printf("%llu\n", next());
    return 0;
}
```

is

```
6004846026386057
6004846115863870
12676181551404632061
```

The output of this Delphi program:

```pascal
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  S: Array [0..1] of UInt64;

function XorShift128: UInt64;
var
  s0, s1: UInt64;
begin
  s1 := s[0];
  s0 := s[1];
  s[0] := s0;
  s1 := s1 xor (s1 shl 23);
  s[1] := (s1 xor s0 xor (s1 shr 17) xor (s0 shr 26));
  Result := s[1] + s0;
end;

procedure GenerateSeed;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to High(S) do
    S[I] := MaxLongInt div 3;
end;

begin
  GenerateSeed;
  Writeln(XorShift128);
  Writeln(XorShift128);
  Writeln(XorShift128);
end.
```

is

```
6004846026386057
6004846115863870
12676181551404632061
```

I note that the C code in the question uses a different seed from your translation. It seeds the state with `-1ULL / 3` and that leads to this output:

```
46820872945684
46912499612351
13066320939010318272
```

To match that in the Delphi code you would use `high(UInt64) div 3`. Do that and you get the output above.

An important note here is that your Delphi code only supplies 64 bits of seed, but your C code supplies 128. I expect that you should supply 128 bits of seed.

Comment: How would one generate a quality seed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436376/what-is-the-most-secure-seed-for-random-number-generation